# Insert into a Oledb database table or update if exists with no Unique Constraint in table

Tags: vb.net, oledb

I'm using OLEDB database with vb.net.
I want to add a record in database table, if record exists then update it else insert record in database table.
I found this Page:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html.
To my application it not works. Below is my code:

```
Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO tblGauge(GaugeID,ItemCode)VALUES( '" + gaugeid_txt.Text + "','" + itemCode_txt.Text + "' ) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE tblGauge SET GaugeID='" + gaugeid_txt.Text + "',ItemCode='" + itemCode_txt.Text + "'", con)
                                If cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() Then
                                    MessageBox.Show("Saved....")
                                End If
```

I'm getting exception for this: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4jhP.png)
Is it possible to do same for OLEDB database? or Is there use another syntax to do update if exists, insert if not in OLEDB?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: There's no such thing as an OLEDB database.  OLE DB is a layer that sits between a database and an application that allows the application to make standard calls instead of having to speak a different language for every database.  There are OLE DB providers for just about every database so the fact that you are using an OLE DB data source is not what's relevant but rather we need to know what the actual database is.  That info is for MySQL so if you're not using MySQL, via an OLE DB provider or not, then that info is irrelevant.

Comment: If you are using MySQL then you might want to go back and read that documentation page again because your code does not look like theirs and, as the error message specifically indicates, yours has no semicolon.

Comment: I don't think you can use `ON DUPLICATE KEY` when there is "no Unique Constraint in table" as you say in your question title. How would the database know what record to update if there is no unique identifier?